# What Is The Time Range For Google Analytics Real Time API

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-api

I'm having no issues using the API with PHP, but when I look at my dashboard on Google Analytics, it says I have 1 real time user, but the data I get back from my API call shows far more than that. This leads me to believe this is over a period of time. What is the time period it is calling? The last 15 mins, 30?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe it might be 30 minutes after some experimenting, but would still like confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: I have to ask are you sure you are loading from the Real-time API and not the Core reporting api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the answer is 30 minutes. Realtime displays pageviews back 30 minutes, not as a snapshot as I had thought.

Answer (score 1):

For real time reports, the session duration of a user is 5 minutes. More info can be found here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en under "Active User Metrics". I'm not sure if this would be any different if the data was accessed through the API though.